# A blogger dropdown menu disappears 20

Tags: jquery

I made an "art gallery" by using Html javascript and CSS ofc, I m wondering how can I make the pictures appear slower on the rectangle panel I made. Should I add more than 5 pictures or that doesn't really matter? I used a template from w3schools... I have two Html pages, the error is in the first one, the second one is just describing the pages whole point.

INDEX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Image slider</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/><!-- ezkell ha akarsz ekezettel irni -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="menu"><!-- sima listaban a menuelemek es azokban egy link -->
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Slider</a></li><!-- ide jon active osztaly, mert ez van alapbol kivalasztva a menuben -->
            <li><a href="about.html">Az alkalmazásról</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="kepek">
            <img src="kepek/001.jpg"></img>
            <img src="kepek/002.jpg"></img>
            <img src="kepek/003.jpg"></img>
            <img src="kepek/004.jpg"></img>
            <img src="kepek/005.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        <ul id="dots"><!-- sima listaban a negyzetek -->
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script><!-- a scriptet a vegere kell rakni mert amugy meghal -->
</html>
```

AZ ALKALMAZASROL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>About</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Slider</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="about.html">Az alkalmazásról</a></li><!-- most ez az .active -->
        </ul>
        <h2>Az alkalmazás szerzőjéről:</h2>
        <br>
        <p>Név: Kovács Gábor<br>
            E-mail: nuukecat@gmail.com<br>
            Alkalmazás neve: Image slider<br>
            Készítés dátuma: 2020.05.28.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT SNIPPET

```
var index = 0; // ez a valtozo tarolja hogy hanyadik kep latszik
slide(); // elinditja a slide -ot
function slide(){
    var i; // csak egy szamlalo valtozo
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); // x tombbe belerakja az osszes elemet ami <img>
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("dot"); // y tombbe belerakja az osszes elemet ami class="dot"
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){ // atmegy az osszes kepen
        x[i].style.display = "none"; // az osszes kepet elrejti, css => display: none;
    }
    index++;// noveli az indext
    if(index > x.length) index = 1; // alaphelyzetbe allitja az index-t, hogy ne menjen tul mint amennyi kep van
    for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){ // atmegy az osszes negyzeten
        y[i].className = y[i].className.replace(" active",""); // kiveszi az "active"-t az elem osztalyabol, igy beszurkul
    }
    x[index-1].style.display = "block"; // lathatova teszi a soron levo kepet, css => display: block;
    y[index-1].className += " active"; // kiemeli a negyzetet, hozzaadja az "active"-t az elem osztalyaihoz
    setTimeout(slide,3000); // lefuttatja a slide() fuggvenyt 3 masodpercenkent
}
```

STYLE

```
*,html { /* minden elemre vonatkozzon es az oldalra */
    padding: 0; /* leveszem a margokat es a parnazast */
    margin: 0;
}
body { /* a testre vonatkozik */
    background: #333; /* hatterszin legyen szurke */
    font-family: arial; /* betutipus arial */
    color: white; /* a betuszin legyen feher */

    display: flex; /* flexboxra allitja az megjeleneset az elemnek */
    flex-direction: column; /* minden ami benne van oszlopba rendezodjon */
    align-items: center; /* kozepre rakjon mindent */
}
@keyframes FadeIn{ /* uj animaciot hoz letre "FadeIn" nevvel */
    from {opacity: 0%;} /* ettol: lathatosag 0% */
    to   {opacity: 100%;} /* eddig: lathatosag 100% */
}
img {
    animation: FadeIn 1s; /* a kepekre rarakom a "FadeIn" animaciot ami 1s hosszu */
}
.dot { /* ezek a negyzetek */
    height: 15px; /* magassag */
    width: 15px; /* szelesseg */
    background: grey; /* szin szurke, alapertelmezett szin */
    margin: 1em; /* eltolom oket egymastol */
}
#dots, #menu {
    list-style: none; /* mind a ketto elemeirol leveszem a stiluspontot mert ronda */
}
#menu li{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    padding:10px;
}
#menu {
    margin: 1em; /* menure pici eltolas */
}
#menu li, .dot { 
    float: left; /* a menu elemeit es a negyzeteket egymas melle rakja */
}
#menu li a { /* a menu elemeinek linkjei */
    padding: 5px; /* kiparnazza picit a feher reszt */
    text-decoration: none; /* leveszi a linkrol az alahuzast */
    color: orange; /* atszinezi narancsra */
}
#menu li:hover{
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: black;
}
.dot.active { /* a menu elemeinek linkjeire ha raviszed a kurzort es az .active osztalyra */
    background: white !important; /* hatterszin feher, !important azert kell hogy felulirja az elozo erteket */
    color: red !important; /* ez igazabol csak a menulinkre vonatkozik mert a negyzetnek nincs szovege */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/w38tp02u/2/

Just set the setTimeout higher so it would be slower.

```js
setTimeout(slide,10000);
```

```js
var index = 0; // ez a valtozo tarolja hogy hanyadik kep latszik
slide(); // elinditja a slide -ot
function slide(){
    var i; // csak egy szamlalo valtozo
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); // x tombbe belerakja az osszes elemet ami <img>
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("dot"); // y tombbe belerakja az osszes elemet ami class="dot"
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){ // atmegy az osszes kepen
        x[i].style.display = "none"; // az osszes kepet elrejti, css => display: none;
    }
    index++;// noveli az indext
    if(index > x.length) index = 1; // alaphelyzetbe allitja az index-t, hogy ne menjen tul mint amennyi kep van
    for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){ // atmegy az osszes negyzeten
        y[i].className = y[i].className.replace(" active",""); // kiveszi az "active"-t az elem osztalyabol, igy beszurkul
    }
    x[index-1].style.display = "block"; // lathatova teszi a soron levo kepet, css => display: block;
    y[index-1].className += " active"; // kiemeli a negyzetet, hozzaadja az "active"-t az elem osztalyaihoz
    setTimeout(slide,10000); // lefuttatja a slide() fuggvenyt 3 masodpercenkent
}
```

```css
*,html { /* minden elemre vonatkozzon es az oldalra */
    padding: 0; /* leveszem a margokat es a parnazast */
    margin: 0;
}
body { /* a testre vonatkozik */
    background: #333; /* hatterszin legyen szurke */
    font-family: arial; /* betutipus arial */
    color: white; /* a betuszin legyen feher */

    display: flex; /* flexboxra allitja az megjeleneset az elemnek */
    flex-direction: column; /* minden ami benne van oszlopba rendezodjon */
    align-items: center; /* kozepre rakjon mindent */
}
@keyframes FadeIn{ /* uj animaciot hoz letre "FadeIn" nevvel */
    from {opacity: 0%;} /* ettol: lathatosag 0% */
    to   {opacity: 100%;} /* eddig: lathatosag 100% */
}
img {
    animation: FadeIn 1s; /* a kepekre rarakom a "FadeIn" animaciot ami 1s hosszu */
}
.dot { /* ezek a negyzetek */
    height: 15px; /* magassag */
    width: 15px; /* szelesseg */
    background: grey; /* szin szurke, alapertelmezett szin */
    margin: 1em; /* eltolom oket egymastol */
}
#dots, #menu {
    list-style: none; /* mind a ketto elemeirol leveszem a stiluspontot mert ronda */
}
#menu li{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    padding:10px;
}
#menu {
    margin: 1em; /* menure pici eltolas */
}
#menu li, .dot { 
    float: left; /* a menu elemeit es a negyzeteket egymas melle rakja */
}
#menu li a { /* a menu elemeinek linkjei */
    padding: 5px; /* kiparnazza picit a feher reszt */
    text-decoration: none; /* leveszi a linkrol az alahuzast */
    color: orange; /* atszinezi narancsra */
}
#menu li:hover{
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: black;
}
.dot.active { /* a menu elemeinek linkjeire ha raviszed a kurzort es az .active osztalyra */
    background: white !important; /* hatterszin feher, !important azert kell hogy felulirja az elozo erteket */
    color: red !important; /* ez igazabol csak a menulinkre vonatkozik mert a negyzetnek nincs szovege */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image slider</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/><!-- ezkell ha akarsz ekezettel irni -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="menu"><!-- sima listaban a menuelemek es azokban egy link -->
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Slider</a></li><!-- ide jon active osztaly, mert ez van alapbol kivalasztva a menuben -->
            <li><a href="about.html">Az alkalmazásról</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="kepek">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/FF0000/FFFFFF">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/FFFF00/000000">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/000000/FFFFFF">
        </div>
        <ul id="dots"><!-- sima listaban a negyzetek -->
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script><!-- a scriptet a vegere kell rakni mert amugy meghal -->
</html>
```